# Passing list of dataframes to R Function

Tags: r

I found a neat function for exporting multiple data frames to an excel file using the package xlsx:

```
save.xlsx <- function (file, ...)
{
  require(xlsx, quietly = TRUE)
  objects <- list(...)
  fargs <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
  objnames <- as.character(fargs)[-c(1, 2)]
  nobjects <- length(objects)
  for (i in 1:nobjects) {
    if (i == 1)
      write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i])
    else write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i],
                    append = TRUE)
  }
  print(paste("Workbook", file, "has", nobjects, "worksheets."))
}
```

It works by putting in the file name and then passing it multiple dataframes like so:

```
 save.xlsx(filename, df1, df2, df3)
```

but i wanted to pass it a list of dataframes instead of them individually like so:

```
dataframes <- list(report1, report2, report3)
save.xlsx(filename, dataframes)
```

but it errors out because I am passing all of the dataframes at once. I am trying to figure out how to unstack them into the function but I haven't been successful yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

David

So i have been trying Richards suggestion and edited to the following:

```
save.xlsx <- function (file, dataframes)
{
  require(xlsx, quietly = TRUE)
  objects <- dataframes
  fargs <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
  objnames <- as.character(fargs)[-c(1, 2)]
  nobjects <- length(objects)
  for (i in 1:nobjects) {
    if (i == 1)
      write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i])
    else write.xlsx(objects[[i]], file, sheetName = objnames[i],
                    append = TRUE)
  }
  print(paste("Workbook", file, "has", nobjects, "worksheets."))
}
```

but i get the following error:

```
Error in .jcall(wb, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;", "createSheet",  : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sheetName must not be null
```

It isn't get the sheet names like it had before but I am not understanding why

Comment: Then don't use `...`, just use a named argument.  Then you can get rid of three lines of the function.

Comment: You may also want to check `openxlsx::write.xlsx`, it can save a list of `data.frame` to a `xlsx` file directly.

Comment: I tried to make the changes Richard suggested but I hit an error I can't figure out how to solve.